# TeXstudio opens always with the same file (solved)

Tags: texstudio, ubuntu

This seems to be a trivial problem, but somehow I did not manage to find a solution.

I bought my new laptop one month ago. I use Ubuntu 18.04 as my OS and installed TeXstudio (2.12.16) through the terminal. It works perfectly, just as it used to do in my previous laptop, with the exception that every time I open TeXstudio it loads always the same file (more concretely the 'Introduction' section from a report I'm writing) instead of opening with a blank page.

This happens no matter if I run the software from the Dock, using the TeXstudio icon through the search option or via the terminal. I have checked the Options panel and could not find anything related to setting a default file to be opened when starting the software.

Comment: Have you tried unchecking the "Restore Previous Session at Startup" option in "Options -> Configure -> General"? (It's only shown if you have "Show Advanced Options" checked)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion (I previously missed the advanced options) but sadly it did not solve the problem. I uncheck the mentioned option, save the changes and close TeXstudio, but when I reopen the program once again that file is loaded and the settings are restored as before. Same happens if I change, for example, the colour scheme; when restarting the program it uses the previous settings, as if the changes had not been saved.

Comment: That sounds like a possible issue with write permissions on TeXstudio's config file. Can you check `~/.config/texstudio/texstudio.ini`? (And if all else fails, maybe you can edit that manually? Deleting `lastSession.txss` might work too (haven't tried).)

Comment: Within the _.ini_ file 2 lines seem to be related to the problem:  one is **Interface\Config%20Riddled=false** and the second one is **Interface\Config%20Show%20Advanced%20Options=false**. Does this look like the reason?

Comment: I don't think it's going to be anything in the file itself - rather, I'm guessing that something is stopping the config file from being updated when you change the settings (so it always reverts to the previous version). Have a look at the permissions on the file, and on the last modification date. But to solve at least your original issue, you could try changing `Files\RestoreSession=true` to `false`.

Comment: As you correctly guessed the _texstudio.ini_ file had 'Read and write' permissions for 'Owner' and 'Group' users, but 'Read only' for 'Others'. In order to become owner of the file and modify the permissions I followed the instructions given [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/803427/644221). Now the changes on the General settings for TeXstudio are saved and properly loaded when reopening the software. The file no longer appears. Thanks @InquisitiveLurker for the useful answers.